# WPF Click on userControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, controltemplate

I wanted to make any grid row inside the container window clickable.
Each row is a usercontrol called "MyBookControl".
when the userControl is clicked, i wanted to raise the command "DownloadCommand".
I'm using mvvm pattern.

container view:  https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3A8F69A0FB413FA4!124&authkey=!ANdfYAk6f0Vf-8s&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

BookControl:

```
<UserControl  x:Name="MyBookControl" />
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.6"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>

        <Label Grid.Row="0">Title</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="1">Author</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="2">Description</Label>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Author}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}" Content="Download" />


        <Ellipse   Grid.Column="3" 
                    Height="20" Width="20"  
                    Stroke="Black" 
                    StrokeThickness="0.5" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   />
        <Controls:PieSlice Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" 
                             Height="20" Width="20" 
                             StartAngle="0" EndAngle="{Binding Percent}"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: You can try adding a `MouseBinding` to your control's `InputBindings` collection: `<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}" />`.

Comment: The entire user control and not just the download button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you, you want to build a responsive panel to hold all your collection members inside. You can try to use a listView control, and put your user control as an item template of  a ListViewItem. There is as select functionality on the house in there (ListView). In this way ListView can be binded to your main viewmodel with a bunch of objects, and each user conntrol can ne binded to a single object.

```
     <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ToYourSourceCollection}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <YourUserControl/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Then you can build a behvior that work around of a ListView events or just listen to a Selected property changes.

Comment: A `ListBox` would be applicable here as well.